# Code splitting and server-side rendering (React is not defined)

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router, babeljs, koa

I am building an isomorphic/universal React app with code-splitting. Even though I manage to compile the client bundle via webpack without issues, the server does not manage to render a page, throwing an error whilst executing the function `renderToString`.

The stack trace is the following when running the server:

```
ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at /xx/src/server/server.js:84:16
    at /xx/node_modules/react-router/lib/match.js:65:5
    at /xx/node_modules/react-router/lib/createTransitionManager.js:118:11
    at done (/xx/node_modules/react-router/lib/AsyncUtils.js:79:19)
    at /xx/node_modules/react-router/lib/AsyncUtils.js:85:7
    at /xx/src/routes/About/index.js:12:7
    at Function.require.ensure (/xx/src/routes/About/index.js:5:10)
    at Object.getComponent (/xx/src/routes/About/index.js:11:13)
    at getComponentsForRoute (/xx/node_modules/react-router/lib/getComponents.js:62:16)
    at /xx/node_modules/react-router/lib/getComponents.js:74:5
---------------------------------------------
    at Application.callback (/xx/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:129:47)
    at Application.listen (/xx/node_modules/koa/lib/application.js:64:43)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/xx/src/server/server.js:103:8)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at loader (/xx/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/xx/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:168:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
```

The server file `server.js` contains:

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import convert from 'koa-convert'
import webpack from 'webpack'
import webpackMiddleware from 'webpack-dev-middleware'
import config from '../../webpack.config'

import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createMemoryHistory, RouterContext, match } from 'react-router';
import { IntlProvider } from 'react-intl'
import { trigger } from 'redial'

import localeMessages from '../locales/en'
import configureStore from '../store/configureStore'


function createPage(html, scriptTag) {
  return `
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
      <body>
        ${html}

        ${scriptTag}
      </body>
    </html>
  `
}

const is_developing = process.env.NODE_ENV == 'development'
const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
const server = new Koa()

server.use((req, res) => {
  const store = configureStore()
  const history = createMemoryHistory(req.path)
  const routes = require('../routes')
  const { dispatch, getState } = store

  match({ routes, history }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    // Get array of route handler components:
    const { components } = renderProps;

    // Define locals to be provided to all lifecycle hooks:
    const locals = {
      path: renderProps.location.pathname,
      query: renderProps.location.query,
      params: renderProps.params,

      // Allow lifecycle hooks to dispatch Redux actions:
      dispatch
    };

    const content = ReactDOM.renderToString(
      <Provider store={store}>
        <IntlProvider locale="en"
                      feedbacks={localeMessages}>
          <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
        </IntlProvider>
      </Provider>
    );

    // Wait for async data fetching to complete, then render:
    trigger('fetch', components, locals)
      .then(() => {
        const state = getState();
        const content = ReactDOM.renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <IntlProvider locale="en"
                          feedbacks={localeMessages}>
            <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
            </IntlProvider>
          </Provider>
        );
        const html = createPage(content, scriptTag)
        resolve({ html, state })
      })
      .catch(e => console.log(e))
  })
})

server.listen(port, '0.0.0.0', () => {
  console.info(`Listening on port ${port} (0.0.0.0)`)
})

server.on('error', (err, ctx) => {
  console.log('error', err, ctx)
})

module.exports = server
```

The whole routine appears to work properly: the state derived from `getState()` looks fine, and the different routes match the expectations (whatever I type on the browser is linked to the proper route) within the loop.

I am following the react-router async routes (as described in this [example](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/tree/master/examples/huge-apps)). In this specific question, the content of the `routes/About/index.js` is:

```
// Polyfill (require for server side)
if (typeof require.ensure !== 'function') require.ensure = (d, c) => c(require)

module.exports = {
  path: 'about',
  getComponent(nextState, cb) {
    require.ensure([], (require) => {
      cb(null, require('./components/About').default)
    })
  }
}
```

I have also double-checked the different components making sure that they all import the React library (ie. `import React from 'react'`). Again, when I run webpack to compile the whole application, there are no problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also have to import React on your `server.js` file because after transpiling the following

```
const content = ReactDOM.renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <IntlProvider locale="en"
                  feedbacks={localeMessages}>
      <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
    </IntlProvider>
  </Provider>
);
```

Looks like this

```
var content = ReactDOM.renderToString(React.createElement(
  Provider,
  { store: store },
  React.createElement(
    IntlProvider,
    { locale: "en",
      feedbacks: localeMessages },
    React.createElement(RouterContext, renderProps)
  )
));
```